# Unable to connect to ftp server

Tags: ftp, connection, powerbuilder

I'm trying to connect to an ftp server through a powerbuilder application using windows api functions. I manage to connect to the ftp server through Internet Explorer (so I don't think it's a permission problem) but the application fails for some unknown reason.

```
String  ls_Null, &
            ls_id
Integer li_rc

li_rc = 1

IF Not InternetAutodial(AUTODIAL_FORCE_UNATTENDED, 0) THEN
    f_write_to_err_log('IMPORT Unable To Connect Internet - Dialup')
    li_rc = -1
ELSE
    SetNull(ls_Null)
    ls_id = "Care_Dsend"
    al_internet_handle = InternetOpen(ls_id, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, ls_Null, ls_Null, 0)        

    IF al_internet_handle > 0 THEN
        al_ftp_connect_handle = InternetConnect(al_internet_handle, is_ftp_url, il_ftp_port, is_ftp_user, is_ftp_password, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, al_ref) 
    END IF
END IF

Return li_rc


//al_internet_handle, al_ftp_connect_handle are by ref long parms
//al_ref is a by ref unsignedlong parm
//is_ftp_url, is_ftp_user, is_ftp_password are strings
//il_ftp_port is long
```

The function manages to return a handle from the InternetOpen api function, but returns 0 from the InternetConnect function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know nothing about powerbuilder, but do you need to specify a proxy?

Comment: No, I don't. As mentioned in another comment, this script works in another application that was written a few years back, and I can't understand why it's not working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the problem was. I was missing **;Ansi** at the end of my function declaration as in :

> Function ulong InternetOpen (ref
>   string lpszAgent, ulong dwAccessType,
>   ref string lpszProxy, ref string
>   lpszProxyBypass, ulong dwFlags)
>   Library "WININET.DLL" Alias for
>   "InternetOpenA **;Ansi**"

Comment: Glad you solved it.  There were some significant changes for Unicode compatibility back in Pb10 - looks like you probably hit this one: http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/New_in_PowerBuilder_10/PB10New_-_Unicode_Support/PB10New_-_Unicode_Related_Chan/PB10New_-_Calling_External_Fun/pb10new_-_calling_external_fun.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your Local External Functions or whatever you are using for `InternetAutodial()`, `InternetOpen()` etc?  Those are not built-in functions (at least not in my Powerbuilder 11.2) and they don't look like PFC. Also, what version of Powerbuilder are you using.

Alternatively, you might want to look at these links:

- [Upload a file using FTP - Real's Powerbuilder HowTo](http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0013.html) (also uses a windows batch file)
- [Internet services example - PFC guide](http://www.pfcguide.com/extensions/ext_0016.asp) (uses PFC)

Comment: Here are the local external functions I'm using: `Function boolean InternetAutodial (ulong dwFlags,ulong dwReserved) Library "WININET.DLL" `
`Function ulong InternetOpen (ref string lpszAgent, ulong dwAccessType, ref string lpszProxy, ref string lpszProxyBypass, ulong dwFlags) Library "WININET.DLL" Alias for "InternetOpenA"` These aren't built-in PB functions but Windows api functions. I'm using PB 11.5 but this exact same functions were used in an an application that was written a few years backin an earlier version of PB and that application works just fine.